# Android 3.2 AVD graphical issues on Retina MacBook Pro running 10.8

Tags: android, macos, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I'm running OSX 10.8 on a recent Retina MBP. I [installed the Android emulator](http://www.juliendesrosiers.com/2012/03/30/how-to-test-web-applications-with-the-android-sdk-on-mac-osx-lion), but I can't get my Android 3.2 emulator to work properly.

The emulator boots up and I can unlock it, but I can't get the apps to open. It starts pulling down the apps screen, but hangs before I can even see any of the icons. The emulator still functions, but the app screen is never actually shown. I can even click the status bar and get the date or pull it down to reveal the notifications.

[image: Android emulator after clicking on Apps]

I had similar graphical issues with my 4.3 emulator, and I was able to fix them by turning on the host GPU. If I try that on the 3.2 emulator, I never see anything on the display. The display is entirely white. When I tried to take a screenshot of it, the screenshot region selection box wiped away the white to reveal the lock screen. Here's a full-screen shot I took to show what it looks like before being wiped:

[image: Android 3.2 emulator with host GPU on]

Here are my settings for the AVD:

[image: Android 3.2 AVD settings]

My ultimate goal is to be able to test web sites on this platform, but it's proving quite a challenge. I don't have an Android device and don't really have a way to get my hands on one at the moment. The emulator seems like the perfect solution if it would only cooperate.

Comment: @UmerFarooq Oh, I thought people only used Windows to test IE compatibility. ;-) Seriously, though, I don't know that it matters why since I don't use either of those environments... although, MacOS *is* essentially Unix.

Comment: Not really. People don't use Windows only for IE compatiblity, that's why it is the leading OS for x86/x64 computers in the world :) . 


As far as your AVD is concerned, re-create it. This should solve your problem. If the problem persists, you can try your app on platform 4.0+. They are the successors of 3.2, so they contain the DNA of 3.2.

Comment: @UmerFarooq I'll try that. I have a 4.3 emulator working. If re-creating the 3.2 AVD doesn't work, testing on only 4.3 may have to be good enough. If anyone else has a fix they've implemented, I'd love to hear it.